# cURL download files issue

Tags: json, curl, wget

When i give the URL (`http://192.168.150.41:8080/filereport/31779/json/`)  in browser, It automatically downloads the file as `31779_report.json`.

Now using i'm trying to download the file using `curl` but i get the following error.

```
$ curl -O http://192.168.150.41:8080/filereport/31779/json/
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

When using the '`-L`' switch , I get the JSON content displayed but the file is not saved.

```
$curl -L http://192.168.150.41:8080/filereport/31779/json/

{

.....
.....

}
```

How to download the exact file "`31779_report.json`" using cURL / wget ?

I don't want the contents to be redirected (`>`) manually to a file (`31779_report.json`).

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you surround the URL with double-quotes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The -O flag of curl tries to use the remote name of the file, but because your URL schema does not end with a filename, it can not do this. The -o flag (lower-case o) can be used to specify a file name manually without redirecting STDOUT like so:

```
curl <address> -o filename.json
```

You can manually construct the filename format you want using awk. For example:

```
URL=http://192.168.150.41:8080/filereport/31779/json/
file_number=$(echo $URL | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-2)}')
file_name="${file_number}_report.json"
curl -L "$URL" -o "$file_name"
```

Hope this is more helpful.

Comment: Thanks Jack, If you read the above question which i have posted using O switch , It throws me some error and also i dont want the content to be redirected to a file.

Comment: Ah, whoops, my bad for skimming too much. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`wget --content-disposition` did the trick for me (https://askubuntu.com/a/77713/18665)

```
$ wget --content-disposition https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/lib32-glibc/download/
...
Saving to: 'lib32-glibc-2.33-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst'
```

Compare to curl:

```
$ curl -LO https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/lib32-glibc/download/
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: (23) Failed writing received data to disk/application
```

And wget without `--content-disposition`:

```
$ wget https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/lib32-glibc/download/
...
Saving to: 'index.html'
```