# Curl - How can I get the filename when browser does, but Curl doesnt?

Tags: curl

I'm trying to perform a simple download. I'm actually using a longer loop and getting the URLs from a filelist, but that's besides the point, since I encounter the error on normal singular Curl query either way, so I'll keep it as simple as possible.

When I try to download one of the files like that:

`curl "https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/1834659595661927431/A2B68B782314829F6BE9DA4034B144DFFD604887/" -O`

I get the following result:

```
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: (23) Failed writing received data to disk/application
```

However, if I copypaste this link into my Edge browser and just try to save the file, when downloading, a name pops up:
`15608770555178647552_screenshots_20220310005322_1.jpg`

How can I force Curl to get this name? What am I missing?

I'm using Windows 10 and the basic Command Prompt (cmd.exe).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I preserve the remote filename when Downloading a file using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451299/how-do-i-preserve-the-remote-filename-when-downloading-a-file-using-curl)

Comment: No, unfortunately. It results in an error: ```0Warning: Remote filename has no length!
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (23) Failed writing header```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unfortunately, as of writing, curl doesn't support UTF-8 filenames in Content-Disposition (see https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1888 ), meaning you'll have to parse it out yourself.. if you have php-cli installed (see https://windows.php.net/ ), you could do

> echo https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/1834659595661927431/A2B68B782314829F6BE9DA4034B144DFFD604887/ | php -r "if(0)var_dump(stream_get_contents(STDIN)); $ch=curl_init();$name='';curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION=>function($ch,string $h)use(&$name):int{$pos=strpos($h,'filename*=UTF-8');if($pos!==false){$name=trim(substr($h,$pos+17,-3));}else{if(0)var_dump($h);} return strlen($h);},CURLOPT_URL=>trim(stream_get_contents(STDIN)) ));$bin=curl_exec($ch);file_put_contents($name,$bin);"

... but good luck doing that with just curl/cmd.exe..

Comment: Thank you, this tool worked, and I had no problem looping it through a larger list :)

Answer (score 3):

Combine `-O` and `-J`

Try

```sh
curl -O -J "https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/1834659595661927431/A2B68B782314829F6BE9DA4034B144DFFD604887/"
```

> If not told otherwise, curl writes the received data to stdout.
> It can be instructed to instead save that data into a local file,
> using the -o, --output or -O, --remote-name options. If curl is
> given multiple URLs to transfer on the command line, it similarly
> needs multiple options for where to save them.

[Source](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html)

Comment: -O and --remote-name result in exactly the same output: curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: (23) Failed writing received data to disk/application. I want the name to be taken from the web, not written by me.

Comment: ah, okay. updated an answer

Comment: The result is now:
```
0Warning: Remote filename has no length!
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (23) Failed writing header
```

Comment: Yes, I copypasted that directly into the Command Prompt.

Comment: The issue you are having now is related to the URL itself. It has to end with the filename. Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175419/curl-download-files-issue)

Comment: This *should* have been the right answer  unfortunately due to missing utf8 filename support in curl, it doesn't. See my answer for more information